# PostgreSQL - How to fetch columns with sum of 1 column value by grouping another 3 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sample Table:

```
    ACC  ACCN   PART    DESC    UT  SITE    QTY  HAZ    SERIAL    S2    STATUS
    TR1  MSR    KKGR     NO     Y   56      2     N                       ST
    TR1  MSR    KUIJ     NO     Y   98      2     N                       HD
    TR1  MSR    KKGR     NO     Y   56      1     N                       ST
    TR2  MSR    KUIJ     NO     Y   98      5     N                       ST
    TR2  MSR    KKGR     NO     Y   56      1     N                       ST
    TR5  MSR    KUIJ     NO     Y   98      5     N                       ST
    TR1  MSR    KUIJ     NO     Y   98      5     N     KKMH              ST
```

Desired result:

```
ACC    ACCN PART    DESC    UT  SITE    QTY HAZ SERIAL  S2  STATUS
TR1    MSR  KKGR     NO     Y   56      3   N                ST
TR1    MSR  KUIJ     NO     Y   98      2   N                HD
TR2    MSR  KUIJ     NO     Y   98      5   N                ST
TR2    MSR  KKGR     NO     Y   56      1   N                ST
```

SQL query to fetch all columns when serial is EMPTY/NULL then group by site and part and status. but The QTY column value = the sum of qty for site,part,status grouping.

I tried with

```
SELECT ACC,
       ACCN,
       PART,
       DESC,
       UT,
       SITE,
       QTY,
       HAZ,
       SERIAL,
       S2,
       STATUS 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE acc IN ('TR1','TR2')
   AND serial = '' 
 GROUP 
    BY (part,site,status)
```

But i got error like:

ERROR: column "mytable.account" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.  It is not clear why you are using `GROUP BY`, on the other hand.

Comment: Perhaps a window function should be used?

Answer (score 0):

From your desired output, it looks like you want to sum the quantity grouped by all other columns in your select.

```
SELECT ACC,
       ACCN,
       PART,
       DESC,
       UT,
       SITE,
   SUM(QTY) as QTY,
   HAZ,
   SERIAL,
   S2,
   STATUS 
FROM mytable 
WHERE acc IN ('TR1','TR2')
AND serial = '' 
GROUP BY ACC,
   ACCN,
   PART,
   DESC,
   UT,
   SITE,
   HAZ,
   SERIAL,
   S2,
   STATUS
```

Comment: In my case i just want to group by (part,site,status). what you suggests Will  work in the same way i want? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should give you, your expected output. Did you try it ?

Comment: Okay. Let me try and get you Varun. Thanks for the support

Comment: Hi Varun, i tried with that one, The QTY is summed up where all the columns are same as we have mentioned all the column values in group by. i just want to sum only by grouping part,site,status.

Comment: Is it different from your desired result ? If yes, then can you show what results you are getting.